# Optimize JVM modules using jlink for a fat Jar file

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system, jlink

One for the coolest feature of JDK9 is [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm) that makes a small optimized version of the JVM to run the application which is pretty useful especially to run the app in a container like a docker one.
However, it's not very simple to just pass the JAR file you have and get an optimized runtime to run it.

Like I use Gradle and create a fat jar file (all the dependencies in a single jar file), and I just simply want to use this jar file to generate the JVM for it? Any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use JDeps to analyze your project's dependencies](https://blog.codefx.org/tools/jdeps-tutorial-analyze-java-project-dependencies/):

```
jdeps --list-deps app.jar
```

Then extract all platform modules (those starting with *java.* or *jdk.*) from that list and feed them into `jlink`:

```
jlink --add-modules $REQUIRED-PLATFORM-MODULES --output jdk-for-app
```

To verify:

```
jdk-for-app/bin/java --list-modules
```

This includes all platform modules you determined as well as their dependencies.

Comment: Nicolai - you might want to expand this a bit to mention service providers that might be needed. jlink can help identify candidate modules to include but it really need someone with a good understanding of the everything in the application to know what might be needed (additional crypto providers for example).

Comment: @AlanBateman Could you point to some references or add your own answer to clarify ?

Comment: I'd add that `--add-modules` accepts a comma separated list (contrary to usual classpath which used to use colons or semicolons depending on the syste,).